# Observer not firing on created object

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use observers to observe a change on my model after XHR. This is because the earlier approach of extending a fn and calling super is not allowed any more.

Running into this weird issue where my observer doesn't fire:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
        console.log('Ember Application ready');
        this.topCampaignsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
            content: null
        });

        App.TopCampaignsModel.create({
            // Calling super is no longer allowed in object instances
            //success: function () {
            //  this._super();
            //  App.topCampaignsController.set('content', this.get('data'));
            //},
            onDataChange: function () {
                console.log('data property on the object changed');
                App.topCampaignsController.set('content', this.get('data'));
            }.observes('data')
        });
    }
});

App.TopCampaignsModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    data: null,

    // this will be actually called from an XHR request
    success: function () {
        this.set('data', [5,10]);
    },

    init: function () {
        console.log('TopCampaignsModel created');
        this.success();
        console.log(this.get('data'));
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gdXfN/26/

Not sure why the console doesn't log "data property on the object changed". Open to alternative approaches on how I can override the 'success' fn in my instance.

Comment: Why do you want to attach a success handler to the AJAX request? This is not idiomatic in ember.  If you are trying to observe the create or update of the model on the server there is a better way.

Comment: I am not using ember-data. All ears to approaches outside that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/c1c720781c976f69fd4014ea50a1fee652286048) in December last year, it is no longer possible to set observers during object creation.  This resulted in a huge performance win.

To set observers on create you need to use:

```
var Object = Object.createWithMixins({
  changed: function() {
  }.observes('data')
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/gdXfN/31/) demonstrating this.

The API documentation should be updated accordingly, something I will do later on.

However, I don't advise you to do that, but instead set observers during object definition.  The same result can be achieved: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/gdXfN/32/

That said, there are two things you are doing that go against Ember concepts:

1. You should not create controller instances yourself, you should let Ember create them for you:

   ```
   App.TopCampaignsController = Em.Controller.extend({ content: null });
   ```

   When the App is initialized, Ember will generate the controller for you.
2. Models should not be aware of controller existence.  Controllers should access models not the other way round.

   Models and Controllers will interact together through routes.

For the last two points, you can watch the tutorial at http://emberjs.com/guides/ to see how the Application, Controllers, Models, and Routes should interact.  Since you're not using 
Ember Data, just ignore `DS.Model` and imagine an `Ember.Object` instead.  The tutorial can give you a pretty good overview of how objects should interact.

Comment: I am not using the Ember routes feature as my url is not changing. In this case then, I have to create the controllers myself. I agree on the model not knowing about the controller point though and i had that for illustration purposes mostly.

Comment: The Ember router is not optional, it's the most important thing. It is the application's state manager and the glue between its components, and you should use it to build your ember app.  The `URL` management in the router is just a bonus that you can easily deactivate: `App.Router.reopen({location: 'none'});`  Here's a fiddle demonstrating how to use routes without urls: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/gdXfN/33/, and here's the generated app: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/gdXfN/33/show/ , notice how there's no URL change.

Comment: So much has changed in the RC releases. I was working with Ember pre releases and the router concept was not there then. Anyhoo, how does it know which template to pick for a route? I see you are using 'ids' instead of data-template-name on your templates.

Comment: Also, for a resource called ImageGallery, If I were to use the route, what would be my template name?

Comment: `id` and `data-template-name` is the same thing, I chose `id` because it's shorter :).  For ImageGallery resource your template should be called `image_gallery`